# LD1117V33C Voltage Regulator only producing 3.28V

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a LD1117V33C Voltage Regulator connected to the output of a 5V regulator (LM7805). There is a 100uF cap across input (9V) and a 10uF cap across the 5V. I'm expecting 3.3V from the regulator but getting 3.28V. I'm getting a steady 4.99/5 from the 7805. My understanding of the LD1117V33C spec is the the max dropout is 1.2V at 800mA. I'm not even close to that so not sure why I'm not getting 3.3.

I'm interfacing an Arduino with an ESP8266 and seeing some weird serial errors when I speed things up a bit (removing debug statements). I have a voltage divider so the Arduino TX 5V is converted to 3.3V for the ESP RX and wondering if that could be causing problems, since it is higher than the voltage of the ESP8266, at 3.28V.[image]

Comment: 3.28 volts from a 3.3 volt regulator is less than a 1% error- should be quite aceptable.

Comment: Your serial issues are much more likely related to parasitic reactance than the fact your power rail is off by 20mV. Scope the Rx and Tx pins at the module.

Comment: The output for the '33C can vary between 3.16V and 3.44V. Your part is (very) within spec.

Comment: Wait, a voltage divider? Try using an actual level shifter instead.

Comment: I don't have a scope so I'll try a logic shifter. I found a few references for logic shifting with the TI SN74AHCT125N (http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SN74AHCT125N/296-4655-5-ND/375798). Seems simple enough.. power with desired output voltage and it will sense the input and convert. The Arduino has no problem with 3.3V so no shifting for the ESP8266 TX.

Comment: You could probably get away with a NPN transistor with the base on +3.3V and the emitter towards the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding of the LD1117V33C spec is the the max dropout is 1.2V at 800mA.

This is true. A dropout voltage is the minimum input voltage required for accurate and **in spec** regulation to happen. At 800mA output, it's VIN needs to be atleast a stable 4.5V.

The output can still vary, due to production tolerances. Your part has a +3% to -6% tolerance on the output specification.  You are seeing just -1.5% which is pretty tight.

Comment: I should have looked closer at the spec. My other vreg power supply is right on at 3.34 and I always see a nearly dead even 5V from my 5V boards, so figured something was wrong. I guess it's nothing to worry about and I could buy a higher quality vreg if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that you have shown your electrolytic capacitors hooked up backwards. The wide striped side of virtually all electrolytic capacitors is the negative terminal....not the positive terminal as you have shown in your pictorial.

[image]

Comment: Good catch. The Fritzing part was labeled incorrectly. The circuit however is connected with the correct polarity